# Did anyone get killed attempting to capture Carmen Sandiego?

Tags: carmen-sandiego

I remember playing the games when I was younger, they were educational, and obviously contained no violence. When you encountered a villain, you were quickly teleported away.

In [Where on Earth Is Carmen Sandiego?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Where_on_Earth_Is_Carmen_Sandiego%3F#cite_note-6) I don't remember the characters having that ability. They did however get into dangerous situations, and Broderbund (the company that owns Carmen Sandiego) had to approve every script.

> The script for every Earth episode had to meet the approval of
> Broderbund, which created and, at the time, owned the Carmen
> franchise. Their cause for concern was the level of the violence on
> other FOX children's shows such as X-Men and Mighty Morphin Power
> Rangers.

Even if they didn't show death, has it been mentioned or hinted that anyone was killed attempting to capture her?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

While his death was circuitously related to an attempt to capture Carmen Sandiego, her father Dexter Wolfe was shot and killed actually trying to confound the police’s attempt to capture her, proving the franchise is not beyond inclusion of unsanitized or explicit violent death.

From the Carmen Sandiego wiki entry for [Dexter Wolfe](https://carmensandiego.fandom.com/wiki/Dexter_Wolfe)

> Wolfe snuck out a window and made a run for his car in hopes to draw the police away from his daughter, but before he could enter the car, a young agent pulled a gun on him, Wolfe raised a hand in surrender and started to pull his car keys out of his pocket, but, believing he was pulling out a weapon, the agent shot and killed him.

So recapping, the police in their attempt to capture Carmen Sandiego, shot and killed Dexter Wolfe, Carmen Sandiego’s father because they erroneously believed he had a weapon while he was aiding and abetting her escape.

Comment: Wow! I didn't know that

Comment: Bear in mind that this describes the 2019 Carmen Sandiego Netflix series, while the original question seems to be about the mid-90s show of more or less the same name.

Comment: @Shadur - I was asking about the mid-90s show, but it doesn't matter. In every iteration of CS I've seen, violence and death are largely avoided on screen (it's suppose to be a kids show after all). At least in the Netflix version they mention a death. Also the 90's show is implied to be a video game were watching, I don't know about the Netflix version.

Comment: @EmpressSvetlana don't forget that the standard for what's been deemed "appropriate for young children" has changed fairly dramatically (for the worse, IMHO) since the 90s when the original aired. Seeing people shot by cops is, unfortunately, no longer so shocking to younger kids. Might be related to an unfortunate scene I saw a few years ago when I witnessed parents strolling down the horror movie aisle with their 4-y-o kid picking movies off the shelf, showing them to mom & dad and putting them in the cart with approval. :(

Comment: @FreeMan What classifies as horror has also greatly changed.  Most movies that terrified people in the '50's would hardly startle a modern audience.  Our standards for the level of realism in effects has made us generally numb to what used to scare the pants off of previous generations.  So a lot of what's in the horror aisle would be perfectly fine for children by today's standards.  (Meanwhile some things in the kids' aisle will terrify even adults - Looking at you, Mike Myers' *Cat in the Hat*...)

Comment: That's quite true, @DarrelHoffman. Of course, we're not shocked by 50's level horror any more because we've slowly gotten used to more and more violence/blood/gore/whatever. It's been a few years since that particular incident, and I'm not a connoisseur of the horror genre, so I couldn't begin to tell you what movies the kid picked, but there were several. Frankly, I can't imagine letting a 4yo pick or watch _anything_ from that section, but that's just me, I guess.

Comment: Also, having never seen the Mike Myers _Cat in the Hat_, I just checked it out on IMDB. I agree 100% - sounds like there's no way that should pass for a kids movie. Of course, after the _Austin Powers_ series, it's to be expected.